# WPF Webbrowser invokeScript from separated JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, wpf, webbrowser-control, invokescript

With a WPF WebBrowser, I'm trying to use a JavaScript method with the code:

```
WebBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", new object[] { if(typeof myMethod == 'function') { myMethod('param'); } });
```

My method :

```
function myMethod(param) {
    alert(param);
}
```

If I put this method directly in my HTML file, it works. But if the method is in a separate file, it doesn't work. The JavaScript file is imported like so:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='../script.js'></script>
```

And it works if I use methods of the script from my HTML page. The problem certainly is that InvokeScript tries to use a method inside my HTML and doesn't import the script.

How can I make this work?

Comment: You are probably invoking it too early, before the browser has downloaded and run the external script file.

Comment: In fact, my page is fully loaded, then I click on a button that launch a C# function, then the InvokeScript() is called....

Comment: tried your code but I can't compile new object[] { if(typeof myMethod == 'function') { myMethod('param'); } }

Comment: If I just call WebBrowser.InvokeScript("myFunction"); it works fine from separate file.

Comment: ok you just forgot to put commas. But your code works fine for me. Cheack that your script is in a folder above the html file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I can use other methods from the script so it is well imported... I'll try with a new project an try to find a solution... At least I know that it should work...

Comment: Did you get to solve it? I have the same problem

Comment: does anyone has a solution?